# SQLITE3 making load file in C

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I'm working with sqlite 3 for the first time ever, and i'm trying to construct a load file to read in information from a CSV file and store it into a table. I think that it deletes the table initally okay, but when i try to add, i get the error message that i wrote "Not sure what response we get from step" Can somebody take a glance at my code and tell me if i'm missing something obvious? Thanks

EDIT: The comparison in the if statement prints out 101 for SQLITE_DONE and 21 for sqlite3_step(sqlstate) but i can't find documentation to understand these codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE 200

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  sqlite3 *db;
  int rc;

  if(argc != 4)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: %s <database file> <table name> <CSV file>\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
    }

    rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
    if(rc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return(1);
    }
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlstate;

    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, "DELETE FROM mytable", -1, &sqlstate, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(sqlstate))
        {
            printf("Not sure what response we got from step");
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }
    }

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[3], "r");
    char line[MAX_LINE];

    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, f) != NULL)
    {
        char query[MAX_LINE] = "INSERT INTO ";
        strcat( query, argv[2]);
        strcat( query, " VALUES (");
        strcat( query, line);
        strcat( query, " );");

        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, query, -1, &sqlstate, 0) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(sqlstate))
            {
                printf("Not sure what response we got from step DONE");
                sqlite3_close(db);
            }
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(sqlstate))
            {
                printf("Not sure what response we got from step DONE1");
                sqlite3_close(db);
            }
        }
    }
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try the simpler `sqlite3_exec()` (documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html).

Comment: @pmg For this project, we can't use _exec or get table.

Comment: There is no code `1101`, but codes that do exist are [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html).

Comment: Call [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) to get a useful error message.

Comment: It was actually 101 not 1101, i added a 1 on accident. So that tells me DONE worked correctly but i cant figure out why my step is 21